# Sub or Function not defined error in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem that I could not solve that untill now.
I put a button on my form. If dont write a code. I can click on it without any problem. If I write some Code and then comment this code I get this error: Sub or function not defined. How can I solve this problem?

```
Private Sub Command40_Click()
'Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
'Dim ts As TextStream
'Dim Name, Line As String
'Dim regn As New regexp
'Dim regx As New regexp
'Dim regend As New regexp
'Dim regxnum As New regexp
'Dim swknnf As Boolean
'Dim matchkennfeld, matchstx, matchend, matchxnum As MatchCollection
' Name = util1.fDateiName("*.DCM", "Text")
' Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
'Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
' set Line = ts.ReadLine
 'regn.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([A-Z 0-9]*)"
  ' regx.Pattern = "\s*(ST/X)\s*([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\s*)+"
  ' regxnum.Pattern = "\s*[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\s*"
  ' regend.Pattern = "\s*(END)\s*"
 ' Set matchkennfeld = regn.Execute(Line)
 ' Set matchstx = regx.Execute(Line)
 ' Set matchend = regend.Execute(Line)
 ' If matchkennfeld.Count <> 0 Then
 '   swknnf = True
 ' End If
 ' If matchend.Count <> 0 Then
 '   swknnf = False
 ' End If
' If matchstx.Count <> 0 And swknnf = True Then
'    Set matchxnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchstx.Item(0)), 5))
'    For Each Match In matchxnum
'      MsgBox Match
'    Next Match
' End If
'Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the existing code (commented lines only) and paste it into Notepad. Open your form in Design View. If the Property Sheet window is already open then just click your `Command40` button to select it, otherwise right-click on your button and choose "Properties".

On the "Event" tab of the Property Sheet, delete any existing value for `On Click`, then click the ellipsis button (`...`) and choose "Code Builder". That will open the VBA editor at the `Sub` that is now defined as the `.OnClick` event handler for the button. Paste your (commented out) code in there.

Return to Access and verify that the button's `On Click` entry now says `[Event Procedure]`. Switch to Form View and click the button. At this point it still shouldn't do anything (because your code is still commented out), but it shouldn't produce an error, either.